# CosmosDB: Count unique values with DISTINCT Subquery Expected Result in Data Explorer but not when using Rest API

Tags: node.js, typescript, azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

Lets say I have a CosmosDB container with the following items.

```json
[
  {
    id: '1',
    position: 'Table flipper'
    city: 'Vancouver'
    type: 'Job'
  },
  {
    id: '2',
    position: 'Table painter'
    city: 'Seattle'
    type: 'Job'
  },  
  {
    id: '3',
    position: 'Table flipper'
    city: 'Calgary'
    type: 'NotJob'
  },
  {
    id: '4',
    position: 'Table maker'
    city: 'Toronto'
    type: 'Job'
  },
  {
    id: '5',
    position: 'Table maker'
    city: 'Vancouver'
    type: 'Job'
  },
  {
    id: '6',
    position: 'Table flipper'
    city: 'Vancouver'
    type: 'Job'
  },
]
```

What I want is the a count of the unique cities given a type.

The query I am running and tried is the following

```sql
SELECT VALUE COUNT(subCollection.city) FROM (
  SELECT DISTINCT (c.city) FROM c
  WHERE c.type = 'Job'
) as subCollection
```

I expect the result to equal the unique number of times a specific city shows up. So in this example the resource from Cosmos should be [3].

Running this query in Azure Portal's Data Explorer the result is [3]. When I run the same query using the REST API, the result is [0]. The actual resource returned from the API is [0, 3].

How I'm using the API:

```js
  let result = await cosmosDb.container(containerName)
    .items.query({
      query: query,
    })
    .fetchAll()

  return result.resources[0] // returns 0
```

I've tried a few combinations of COUNT / DISTINCT but I get the same discrepancy between API and Data Explorer. I've also tried including a continuation token in the API.

Any ideas what I am doing wrong and why results are different from the REST API vs Data Explorer?

Comment: There's a very similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50607120/272109) - do any of the answers solve your issue?

Comment: @DavidMakogon Thanks for the reply. I did see this prior to asking but I still get the same result where the API call is different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- I have used `runQuery` function which encapsulates the logic for executing the query against COSMOS DB.
- And a new instance of `CosmosClient` is created. Then, a reference to the desired container within the specified database is obtained using the `database()` and `container()` methods.
- Using the `query()` method, the container is queried, and the `fetchAll()` function is used to retrieve every result.
- By using the `runQuery()` function, `then()` block outcome is result. Any errors are captured in the `catch()` block.

**Here is the code to get expected result as in Data Explorer using Rest API:**

```js
const { CosmosClient } = require("@azure/cosmos");
async  function  runQuery() {

// Replace with your Cosmos DB endpoint url
const  endpoint = "https://**********";

// Replace with your Cosmos DB primary key
const  key= "************";

const  containerName = "Items";

const  client = new  CosmosClient({ endpoint, key });

const  container = client.database("NewDb").container(containerName); //Replace with your DB name

const  query = `
SELECT VALUE COUNT(subCollection.city) FROM (
SELECT DISTINCT c.city FROM c WHERE c.type = 'Job'
) AS subCollection`;

const { resources } = await  container.items.query(query).fetchAll();
return  resources;
}

runQuery()

.then((result) => {
console.log(result);
})
.catch((error) => {
console.error("Error running the query:", error);
});
```

**Items:**
[image]
**Output:**
[image]

Comment: Be cautious, SELECT VALUE COUNT(subCollection.city) FROM (
SELECT DISTINCT ...) may not return the right result for a cross-partition query. Experiment with the query first